# Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string with google charts

Tags: javascript, php, json, charts, google-visualization

I am using PHP to populate a google area charts from a phpMyAdmin database. There are only two columns of data: Date and Price. Below is my code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        <?php
        $sql = "SELECT price, date FROM prices LIMIT 5;";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        $data = [];
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          $data[] = [$row['price'], $row['date']];
        }
        ?>
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([<?= json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);?>]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Price History',
            hAxis: {
              title: 'Date',
              titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}
            },
          vAxis: {
            minValue: 0,
            title: "price",
            format: 'currency',
            explorer: {
              actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'],
              keepInBounds: true,
              maxZoomIn: 1.0}
            },
        };
```

The json data table that I'm getting looks like this:

```
[{"date":"2020-04-20 00:00:00","price":1},
{"date":"2020-05-09 18:05:02","price":1.02},
{"date":"2020-05-09 18:05:27","price":1.02},
{"date":"2020-05-09 18:05:06","price":1.0192233756},
{"date":"2020-05-09 18:05:35","price":1.0264162619}]
```

However, I keep getting the error "Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string". I have never used google charts before this, so I don't really even know what that means or how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

google's `arrayToDataTable` method expects a simple array of values,
with no objects / object keys...

try adding just the values in the php...

```
    $sql = "SELECT date, price FROM prices LIMIT 5;";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $data = [];
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $data[] = [$row['date'], $row['price']];  // <-- values only here
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting the same error using this method.

Comment: will you please share the rest of the code that draws the chart? (edit the question)

Comment: I've udpated the question to include all the related code.